# Maven MojoExecutionException using Checkmarx on JSproject

Tags: maven, checkmark

I am using checkmarx maven plugin to perform a checkmarx scan on my javascript base project (Angular 1.6).

When I run the command `mvn checkmarx:scan` in output I have the error bellow.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.116 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-03T17:23:31+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/217M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.checkmarx.maven:checkmarx-maven-plugin:8.5.0:scan (default-cli) on project gbis-wms-common-web-client: You must set at least one file.
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any idea? thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

The solution were to add a sourceDirectory> tag in the build section of my pom.xlm and it works. **see bellow :**

```
<build>
    ...
    <sourceDirectory>./src</sourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```